# Salesforce Flows with Cross Org Adapter

Tags: salesforce-connect

My requirement is sync the opportunity records of 2 Salesforce Orgs into 1 Org and get the consolidated sales values.
As a solution I have created External Objects for the Opportunity from the 2 seperate Orgs using Salesforce Connect Cross Adapter. As Cross Object Adapter does not support CDC not able to capture the data change happening in the external objects. Can we use flows to track the record change in the external object and update/create new opportunity records in the destination org.